# Replace a string including a slash "/" using sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed

How do I replace a string `I1Rov4Rvh/GtjpuuYttr==` with `mytest` in a file `mtestsed.properties` with `sed` command?

I have tried:

```
sed -e -i 's/I1Rov4Rvh/GtjpuuYttr==/mytest/g' mtestsed.properties
```

Comment: Swap your `-e` and `-i`.  `-e` accepts an *argument.*

Comment: Also, *never* use `-i` on a sed command you are not sure about.  If you've got it wrong, you've irrevocably edited your file the wrong way.  Try *without* `-i` first, always.  Pipe to `less` if it's a big file.

Comment: would help if the person downvoting this question adds the reason... also I don't get why there are two votes to close the question...

Comment: I edit title to include / as I think that is the origin of the problem. I also see no reason to VTC or downvote.

Answer (score 15):

sed delimiter can be any char, precisely for occasion where you need to replace a string with `/`

either

- escape `/` symbol:

  ```
  sed -i 's/I1Rov4Rvh\/GtjpuuYttr==/mytest/g'
  ```
- use another separator:

  ```
  sed -i 's|I1Rov4Rvh/GtjpuuYttr==|mytest|g'
  ```

  ```
  sed -i 's:I1Rov4Rvh/GtjpuuYttr==:mytest:g'
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! It's worked for me!

Comment: See [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/766595/properly-escaping-forward-slash-in-bash-script-for-usage-with-sed)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the `/` in the text you want to replace. This is a special character for `sed` and therefore you need to escape it with a `\`. Also as pointed out in the comments: the command also fails because of the `-e` option which expects a script.

This should work:

```
sed -i 's/I1Rov4Rvh\/GtjpuuYttr==/mytest/g' mtestsed.properties
```

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice that.  But it's not that `-e` is *unneeded.*  Including it where it was included will *prevent* the command from working.  (It will make Sed try to run `-i` as a command on the two files `s/I1Rov4Rvh/GtjpuuYttr==/mytest/g` and `mtestsed.properties`.  But `-` isn't a valid command code.)

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the `/` is not really special for the `s` command, it's just common practice to use it, but you could use almost everything else as delimiter. As soon as there are slashes in the search pattern or the replacement string, I prefer choosing a different delimiter instead of messing around with backslashes. Use `s/_1Rov4Rvh/GtjpuuYttr==_mytest_g` for example.